# Spring boot: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and having with error while running my application.
I'm following a tutorial and I believe I'm having proper parent and dependencies with POM, please help me

main class:

```
package com.boot;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */

@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, "hello");
    }
}
```

error is:

```
   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        at com.boot.App.main(App.java:18) [classes/:na]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

POM :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
  <name>das-boot</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Post the *entire* stack trace. There's an additional line in there directly from Tomcat, probably saying that you already have something open on the port.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try to change the port number in `application.yaml` (or `application.properties`) to something else.

Comment: I can't find this directory which IDE are you referring to?
However when I set this port programatically it's working although I have to change the port on every run .. please suggest how to fix this.
`System.getProperties().put( "server.port", 130 );`

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-rest-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: ..although my application did not have this configuration file.  The TCP port conflict was the problem, so this post was still very helpful.  The key errors were: Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler and java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Answer (score 15):

You need to add the tomcat dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have this dependency, still getting the exception org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Answer (score 5):

If you are running on a linux environment, basically your app does not have rights for the default port.

Try 8181 by giving the following option on VM.

`-Dserver.port=8181`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had multiple errors where the first one was: ,,Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container". I tried to solve the first one multiple times, but the real problem was in the rest of them. Turns out I had two different imports of the Logger, so when I tried to initialize it there wasn't a compile problem but it was a runtime error.

My advice: check all the error you have, maybe the problem is not in the first one as I initially thought. So maybe solution to this problem is in the next displayed error.

If this is the only error you have, the solution is probably on of the above answers.

Answer (score 2):

In my condition when I got an exception " Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container",

I opened the debug mode of spring boot by adding `debug=true` in the application.properties,

and then rerun the code ,and it told me that `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String`

Thus, we know that probably I'm using a servlet API of lower version, and it conflicts with spring boot version.

I went to my pom.xml, and found one of my dependencies is using servlet2.5,
and I excluded it.

Now it works. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I just had to put a -X flag with `mvn`. Look at the debug log; there was an issue with Spring while locating the .properties file.

Answer (score 2):

This could happen due to the change in java version of the project.Say for example if the project is build in java 8 and if we change the java version to 11 then there can be such issue. In intellij idea go to the **File->Project Structure** then change the **Project SDK Version**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Tomcat Dependency and also extend your Application Class from extends SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication  
public class App extend SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, "hello");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to handle this is to include this in your application.properties or .yml file:
`server.port=0` for application.properties and `server.port: 0` for application.yml files. Of course need to be aware these may change depending on the springboot version you are using.
These will allow your machine to dynamically allocate any free port available for use.
To statically assign a port change the above to `server.port = someportnumber`. If running unix based OS you may want to check for zombie activities on the port in question and if possible kill it using `fuser -k {theport}/tcp`.
Your .yml or .properties should look like this.

`server:
  port: 8089
  servlet:
    context-path: /somecontextpath`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was in XML migrations. I deleted all tables and sequences and it works on next bootRun

Answer (score 0):

As said above, if you are running on a Linux, your app does not have access to 80 port. There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. Run your application with root previlegies - good idea only for local
   testing, not for any production.
2. Run app at port 8081 for example, setup reverse-proxy with nginx, and redirect requests from 80 to 8081.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might have used Mapping incorrectly one of your, if not more, entities. Fix that. And the error should go away.

In my case, I forgot that I mapped two entities and left one of them with an object annotated with @OneToMany. I commented out and I am now rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

Though may not be OP's solution, my search brought me here, and then I figured out what my issue was causing this same error message.

My application-beta.yml was named properly to match my run configuration > active profile setting (my IDE = intelliJ). However, I missed one spot in the yml file where a property needed to be set:

```
spring:
  profiles: betarclocal
```

needed to be changed to match the "beta" active profile:

```
spring:
  profiles: beta
```

Simply overlooked this and all the properties in the yml config under this were being ignored... And one of the properties were needed for the tomcat server.

Long story shory: make sure your active profiles, spring profiles, and application-[activeprofile].yml are all named uniformly.