# Problems with launch spring boot jar on ubuntu server. Error starting ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ubuntu, deployment

I have configured nginx to fit my code. My code works well on Windows and now I'm trying to deploy it to Ubuntu. I run jar and it fail. **Logs**:

```
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.2)
    
    2021-03-13 06:52:55.131  INFO 4305 --- [           main] com.social.socialmedia.Application       : Starting Application v1.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_282 o
    n amber with PID 4305 (/home/kirill/social-media-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by kirill in /home/kirill)
    2021-03-13 06:52:55.149  INFO 4305 --- [           main] com.social.socialmedia.Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles:
    default
    2021-03-13 06:53:00.135  INFO 4305 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mod
    e.
    2021-03-13 06:53:00.515  INFO 4305 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 332 ms. Found
     2 JPA repository interfaces.
    2021-03-13 06:53:03.824  INFO 4305 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.meth
    od.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@1fb700ee' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is
     not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2021-03-13 06:53:03.861  INFO 4305 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springfr
    amework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not elig
    ible for auto-proxying)
    2021-03-13 06:53:06.121  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
    2021-03-13 06:53:06.194  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2021-03-13 06:53:06.195  INFO 4305 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
    2021-03-13 06:53:06.517  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2021-03-13 06:53:06.518  INFO 4305 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1
    1035 ms
    2021-03-13 06:53:08.111  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2021-03-13 06:53:08.596  INFO 4305 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.27.Final
    2021-03-13 06:53:09.579  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    2021-03-13 06:53:10.113  INFO 4305 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2021-03-13 06:53:11.762  INFO 4305 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2021-03-13 06:53:12.004  INFO 4305 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQ
    LDialect
    2021-03-13 06:53:19.889  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hiberna
    te.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    2021-03-13 06:53:19.925  INFO 4305 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit
     'default'
    2021-03-13 06:53:22.331  WARN 4305 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore,
     database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
    2021-03-13 06:53:27.076  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.securit
    y.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2364305a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@72445aba, or
    g.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7829b776, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@4b3c354a, org.springframework.security.we
    b.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@56f6d40b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5536379e, org.springframe
    work.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1c80e49b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@15c25153
    , org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@470a696f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5b
    64c4b7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1433046b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityIntercep
    tor@350ec41e]
    2021-03-13 06:53:28.106  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.531  WARN 4305 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - can
    celling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springfr
    amework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.543  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.553  INFO 4305 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'de
    fault'
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.568  INFO 4305 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.612  INFO 4305 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.622  INFO 4305 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.751  INFO 4305 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2021-03-13 06:53:30.885 ERROR 4305 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.W
    ebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!
    /:5.3.3]
            at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3
    .3]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:591) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot
    -2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at com.social.socialmedia.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [social-media-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) [social-media-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [social-media-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [social-media-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
            at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.
    2]
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar!/:5.3.3]
            ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.
    4.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]
            ... 25 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1067) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:240) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            ... 27 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:228) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:211) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1159) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:603) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1064) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar!/:9.0.41]
            ... 29 common frames comitte
```

**My propeties**:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/socialmedia
   spring.datasource.username=postgres
   spring.datasource.password=root
   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
   spring.jpa.show-sql=false
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
   spring.flyway.enabled=false
   spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
   spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

**continues code:**

upload.path=home/kirill/uploads

#properties for MailSender

#smptps - Not secure connection

spring.mail.host=smtp.yandex.ru

#test

spring.mail.username= HIDED EMAIL

spring.mail.password=password

spring.mail.port=465

spring.mail.protocol=smtps

mail.debug=false

recaptcha.secret=hided secret

spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION

hostname= HIDED HOST

server.port=80

**Everywhere I looked for solutions, I did not find anything. I don't understand this error**

Comment: Your problem is not with the application instead, you might have another process running port 80 nginx is already running there try changing you application port to something 8080 or different more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579432/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embedded-tomcat-servlet-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the application on port 80.

```
server.port=80
```

Ports < 1024 are only allowed to run as root.

Either run it as root (not recommended) or use another port.