# Exception faced while starting up spring application after upgrading spring-boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting the following error when I upgraded spring boot starter parent version from 2.0.4.RELEASE to 2.6.9

During startup, it is giving error related to 'errorChannel' subscriber.

```
    Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8000"]
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
Removing {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
Channel 'abc.errorChannel' has 0 subscriber(s).
stopped bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.getTargetBean(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:371) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:336) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1058) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1021) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1652) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.destroy(DefaultBinderFactory.java:121) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:559) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1163) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:520) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1156) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1106) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:596) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:420) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
    at com.dt.cms.DTCmsApplication.main(DTCmsApplication.java:52) ~[classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_341]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.9.jar:2.6.9]
Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
Pausing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8000"]
Stopping service [Tomcat]
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:817)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:817)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-timer-4-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick(HashedWheelTimer.java:600)
 io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:496)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-11] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-12] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-13] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [redisson-netty-2-14] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:198)
 sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:117)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
 sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:101)
 io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:68)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:813)
 io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
 io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

can someone tell what I am missing?

Spring boot starter parent version : 2.6.9

Spring boot admin version : 2.6.9

Spring cloud version : 2020.0.3

JAVA version : 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579432/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embedded-tomcat-servlet-container)

Comment: No, it didn't solve the problem. Port number is not the issue

Comment: And did you check for others answer as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585142/10952503) which propose something different

Comment: @Elikill58 this also didn't work